# Is 8th mile about Eminem himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, 8-mile

In the end of the 8 mile when Eminem tells his friend that he is going to "do his own thing", what exactly does he mean? Do those words imply he will try to pursue his rap career and go to California, which eventually will lead him to meeting with Dre?

Comment: From my understanding, the movie has nothing to do with Eminem's actual life, it is a movie about a white rapper named Jimmy Smith Jr, when Eminem's real name is Marshall Mathers, so I don't think he has any intention of meeting Dre, I think it just means he is looking to gain success on his own and he's going to try and pursue his rap career more in depth now that he's broken the barrier that kept him from winning battles in the past.

Comment: However, producers still kept some obvious similarities such as him living in a trailer home, having a sister, getting beat up badly etc.

Comment: Either way, it was never meant to be a story about his life exactly, just kind of took some details of his life, and made them part of the story line.  I'm just saying that I don't believe he meant anything about meeting Dre in the movie, I think it just meant that he wanted to try and find success on his own, and continue to build "B Rabbit's" name in the rap community.

Comment: @eYe Unfortunately, the similarities between B. Rabbit and Eminem are the same as comparing B. Rabbit to any white kid living in low to middle class America.  Lives in a trailer, has a sister and gets beat up badly?.....could be anyone.

Comment: @eYe I think that your question is good without the last sentence regarding Dre.  This implies that you believe the film is a bio-pic about Eminem, which it is not.